# jQuery validation if not empty number

Tags: jquery, validation

I use this plugin for jquery validation: http://jqueryvalidation.org

This is not problem when I need: required, required number etc., I just put in element class like this:

```
<input type="text" id="" value="" name="name"size="40" class="required"
```

In my example I need required number but only if is input not blank, when i use

```
    <input type="text" id="" value="" name="name"size="40" class="required number"
```

user can't leave this input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

leave out `required`

```
<input type="text" id="" value="" name="name"size="40" class="number" />
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5swW4/)